# Adding favicon/icon to browser address bar

Tags: google-chrome, browser, favicon

I recently noticed that [Trello](https://trello.com) has their company logo *inside* of the address bar in Google Chrome. Looking through the [Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/browser-customization/) page, It isn't clear how this is done.

[image]

My current browser customisation meta tags:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png" />
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest" />
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#000000" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
```

Any pointers or recommendations would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm using Trello and can't observe this icon. Could you give more context about it? Is it desktop Chrome or Android Chrome? Anything specific? (you are using a dark theme?)